# Group result by matching two columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a table called `Messages` where I store user messages each user send to other users. The table structure is like below.

```
+--------+----------+-----------------+------------+
| Sender | Receiver |     Message     |    Date    |
+--------+----------+-----------------+------------+
| John   | Dennis   | How are you     | 2015-06-06 |
| John   | Dennis   | Hi              | 2015-06-05 |
| Tom    | John     | How much is it? | 2015-06-04 |
| Tom    | John     | Did you buy it? | 2015-06-03 |
| Robin  | Tom      | Hey man         | 2015-06-03 |
| Dennis | John     | What up         | 2015-06-02 |
| John   | Tom      | Call me         | 2015-06-01 |
+--------+----------+-----------------+------------+
```

I want to get the newest message and other participants' name for a selected user for each conversation. For a example there are three conversations. One is between "john-Dennis" and 2nd one is "John-Tom"and 3rd one between "Robin-Tom".

If I want to get conversations for user `john`, I want to get the latest conversation message with the name of other user who is in the conversation.

The expected result for the above scenario should be like this.

```
+-------------+-----------------+------------+
| Participant |     Message     |    Date    |
+-------------+-----------------+------------+
| Dennis      | How are you     | 2015-06-06 |
| Tom         | How much is it? | 2015-06-04 |
+-------------+-----------------+------------+
```

How to achieve this using a SQL query in SQL Server. I am struggling with part for days. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what you want is the most recent message sent by the selected user and the most recent message received by the selected user? In your example, selected user is John

Comment: Are you getting an error?   You should post your latest attempt so we can see where you are going wrong and help you rather than just doing your work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to compress this a bit, but I've split it into simple steps to hopefully make it a little easier to follow.

```
-- Sample data from the question.
declare @msg table (Sender varchar(32), Receiver varchar(32), [Message] varchar(max), [Date] date);
insert @msg
    (Sender, Receiver, [Message], [Date])
values
    ('John','Dennis', 'How are you', '2015-06-06'),
    ('Dennis', 'John', 'Hi', '2015-06-05'),
    ('Tom', 'John', 'How much is it?', '2015-06-04'),
    ('Tom', 'John', 'Did you buy it?', '2015-06-03'),
    ('Robin', 'Tom', 'Hey man', '2015-06-03'),
    ('Dennis', 'John', 'What up', '2015-06-02'),
    ('John', 'Tom', 'Call me', '2015-06-01');

-- The name of the user whose conversations you want to find.
declare @UserName varchar(32) = 'John';

-- Step 1: Create columns [Participant1] and [Participant2] that will be the same for
--         each pair of users regardless of who's the sender and who the receiver.
with NameOrderCTE as
(
    select 
        Participant1 = case when Sender < Receiver then Sender else Receiver end,
        Participant2 = case when Sender < Receiver then Receiver else Sender end,
        *
    from
        @msg
),

-- Step 2: For each distinct pair of participants, create a [Sequence] number that 
--         puts the messages in reverse chronological order.
MessageSequenceCTE as
(
    select
        *,
        [Sequence] = row_number() over (partition by Participant1, Participant2 order by [Date] desc)
    from
        NameOrderCTE
)

-- Step 3: Get the most recent ([Sequence] = 1) messages for each conversation
--         involving the target user.
select
    Participant = case @UserName when Sender then Receiver else Sender end,
    [Message],
    [Date]
from
    MessageSequenceCTE
where
    @UserName in (Sender, Receiver) and
    [Sequence] = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is a additional question. What if i want to join another table contains user master details and get address of the participant. where should i add the join query.

Comment: You can add any joins to the `select` statement in step 3. Steps 1 and 2 are strictly concerned with the filtering process, so you shouldn't need to add anything to them unless you want the additional data to somehow affect which records ultimately get selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select a.Reciver as Participant,a.message,a.Date from message a
join(select sender,Receiver,max(date) from message where Sender = 'John'  group by sender,Receiver) b
on a.sender=b.sender and a.Receiver=b.Receiver and a.Date=b.date
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should give you what you need :

```
SELECT a.Sender, a.Receiver, a.Message, a.[Date]
FROM 
(
   SELECT m.* , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
   CASE 
     WHEN m.Sender = 'John' THEN 1 
     ELSE 2 
   END 
   ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS rn
   FROM message m
   WHERE m.Sender = 'John' or m.Receiver ='John'
)a WHERE rn= 1
```

Comment: A little change to outer select :  `SELECT CASE WHEN a.Sender = 'John' then a.Receiver ELSE a.Sender END AS Participant` ... Why don't ask what is really needed from the very beginning ?

Comment: Sory for the inconvenience. I ll check

Comment: This does not work well. For example , when there is a conversation , Let's assume it with `Phaul`. when only `Philip` have send messages to john. but john doesn't have replied yet. That means john doesn't have send any messages to `Phal` yet . Those conversations does not listed in this result set. :(

Answer (score 0):

Base on my understanding, this do the job. Although it isn't the most performing solution because of tempDb access.

```
DECLARE @SelectedUser   NVARCHAR(100) = 'John'

SELECT TOP 1    Participant = Receiver,
                [Message],
                [Date]
INTO #tmp
FROM [Messages]
WHERE Sender = @SelectedUser
ORDER BY [Date]


SELECT *
FROM #tmp
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 Participant = Sender,
       [Message],
       [Date]
FROM [Messages]
WHERE Receiver = @SelectedUser
ORDER BY [Date]
```

Comment: I added a capital J to John to match your dataset. If you tryied and had a empty resultset. Retry with capital J.