# Bring back the total amount of products and services sold by each employee for 2018

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking to bring back a result to show how much each employee has sold.
So far i have created code to show just the products as seen below.

```
SELECT 
    Booking.*, 
    Employee_Details.* 
FROM 
    Employee_Details 
INNER JOIN
    Booking ON Booking.Employee_ID_FK = Employee_Details.Employee_ID
WHERE
    Booking_Date LIKE '%2018%' 
ORDER BY 
    Employee_ID_FK
```

This worked however i also wanted to include the services and therefore tried to add this but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is what i tried:

```
SELECT 
    Booking.*, 
    Employee_Details.*, 
    Products.*, 
    Services.Charge_Per_Service
FROM 
    Employee_Details 
    INNER JOIN Booking ON Booking.Employee_ID_FK = Employee_Details.Employee_ID 
    INNER JOIN Products ON Booking.Product_Name_FK = Products.Product_Name
    INNER JOIN Services ON Booking.Service_Name_FK = Services.Service_Name 
-- WHERE Booking_Date LIKE '%2018%' ORDER BY Employee_ID_FK
```

However this didn't work. I tried taking out the Where but this didn't work either. Can anyone exlpain what needs to be done? Also if we could specify the year (2018) as seen commented on the above code that would be great!

Please see below for links to my tables used:

[Please see here for my Booking Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2YS9.png)

[Please see here for my Employee Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6fMZ.png)

[Please see here for my Product Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN7lp.png)

[Please see here for my Services Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1NBE.png)

Comment: Could you post format data instaed of image thanks

Comment: Yes, table definitions would be much easier to work with than screenshots. Also it would help if you could be more specific than "this didn't work." What results are you getting, and what results are you trying to get?

Comment: Sorry how do i show this as a table definition? @JoeFarrell The second runs however no results appear.

Comment: What is your expect result?

Comment: @RyanPease, you can either insert a textual representation of your tables into your question, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146053/group-result-by-matching-two-columns-in-sql-server/31146377#31146377), or if you want to be really helpful, you could use a tool like [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) to compose your sample data set and share the link in your question.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `OUTER JOIN` base on Booking table from `Products` and `Services` because you use `inner join` that will consider all table value condition value from your sample data that will no row match.

There is a method `year` can get the year number from date type value.

```
SELECT 
    Booking.*, 
    Employee_Details.*, 
    Products.*, 
    Services.Charge_Per_Service
FROM 
    Booking
    INNER JOIN Employee_Details ON Booking.Employee_ID_FK = Employee_Details.Employee_ID 
    LEFT JOIN Products ON Booking.Product_Name_FK = Products.Product_Name
    LEFT JOIN Services ON Booking.Service_Name_FK = Services.Service_Name
WHERE yaer(Booking_Date) = 2018 
ORDER BY Employee_ID_FK
```

Comment: Hi there, this works however it doesn't show the products. I Need the table to show both the services as well as the products.

Comment: @RyanPease Could you post your expect result?

Comment: Nope sorry totally my bad, this worked i just didn't have the data and therefore there was nothing to display.